# How to add header to GridView in android?

Tags: android, gridview

Hi can anyone help with [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java)

I am getting Half Header for the `GridView`

[image]

Comment: Check `width` of your header in `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was so stuck in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially i didn't analysed the entire code and when i gone through [GitHub code](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter/blob/master/src/in/srain/cube/views/GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter.java) instead of [code given in google doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java) i found solution that, in google doc they didn't set column width for different Target-API's and i solved the problem by just replacing the [Google source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java) by [GitHub code](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter/blob/master/src/in/srain/cube/views/GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter.java) [image]